# In SQL, how do I pivot on a bit value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query is designed to create an attendance history for each pupil in a given class.  The Pupil table contains IDs, names and academic details, while the Register table has only four columns: ID, StudentID, Time (Datetime) and Present (bit).  On its own the table works fine and casts the bit values as ints, so I get:

```
Jim Monday 1
Jim Tuesday 0
Sally Monday 1
Sally Tuesday 1
```

But when it's pivoted using the code below, all of the values for every pupil show as NULL:

```
Name Monday Tuesday
Jim Null Null
Sally Null Null
```

When I want this:

```
Name Monday Tuesday
Jim 1 0
Sally 1 1
```

Perhaps I've been staring at it too long.  I'd really appreciate any help.  Thanks!

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 

select @cols = STUFF(  (SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Register.Time)
FROM Register INNER JOIN Pupil on Register.StudentID = Pupil.StudentID 
WHERE Pupil.GroupDesignation = 'ClassDesignationGoesHere' 
GROUP BY Register.Time ORDER BY Register.Time ASC 
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') 

set @query = 'SELECT FName, SName, ' + @cols + ' FROM 
( 
SELECT Pupil.FName, Pupil.SName,  CAST(Present AS TINYINT) AS INTPresent, Register.Time  
FROM Register INNER JOIN Pupil ON Register.StudentID = Pupil.StudentID  
WHERE Pupil.GroupDesignation = ''ClassDesignationGoesHere''  
) x 
PIVOT (MAX(INTPresent) for Time in (' + @cols + ') ) p '  execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use data type `bit` in `Max` or `min` operator.

you need to convert it into `Int` in `Pivot` source query

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT NAME,
               dates,
               CONVERT(INT, flag) flag
        FROM   result)a
       PIVOT (Max(flag)
             FOR dates IN([Monday],
                          [Tuesday])) piv
```

Hope you can convert this to `Dynamic pivot`

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfaaf/1)

Comment: Thanks for for the reply. Is that not achieved by my cast statement?

Comment: @EdFearon `Tinyint` is also working check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfaaf/2. There is something wrong with your data

Comment: It must be something to do with the dynamic element.  I changed the Present column from bit to int to get rid of the issue and the result is the same.  I might need a new question...

Comment: I found two problems that have fixed it.  First, I was using 'Time' which is a reserved word.  Second, the dynamic column heading thing doesn't work with datetime values - once I changed the dates so that they are stored as text, it all worked.  Thanks for your help!